# Magento 2.3 Frontend module page blank

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, module, layout

I'm trying to create a simple frontend module on Magento 2.3.2,
It seems to work, but I see a blank content on frontend.

I have this folder structure

```
-app
    -code
        -MyVendor
            -MyModule
                -Block
                    --Index.php
                -Controller
                    -Index
                        --Index.php
                -etc
                    --module.xml
                    -frontend
                        --routes.xml
                -view
                    -frontend
                        -layout
                            --mymodule_index_index.xml
                        -templates
                            --homepage.phtml
```

These are the files

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyVendor_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="myurl" id="myurl">
            <module name="MyVendor_MyModule"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Block/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/mymodule_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Index" name="mymodule_index_index" template="MyVendor_MyModule::homepage.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml

```
<h2>This is a custom module</h2>
```

Then I executed this commands

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Then I go to https://www.example.com/myurl/index/index
I can see the theme, but no title and no "This is a custom module"

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layout from `mymodule_index_index.xml` to `myurl_index_index.xml`.

Comment: Thank you man! You are my life saver :D

Answer (score 1):

the layout file will have name as format: {router_id}_{controller_name}_{action_name}.xml.

You can understand the layout in detail in this Magento topic , and the instruction of a layout structure.

When rendering page, Magento will check the layout file to find the handle for the page and then load Block and Template. We will create a layout handle file for this module:

```
Change the layout from mymodule_index_index.xml to myurl_index_index.xml.
```

for better understand please follow the below guide

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html